# How to make a runnable jar file?

Tags: java, jar

There was a program that I used that made runnable .jar files.. All the ones I'm finding now are ones that make .exe files.. I remember it also has the option to make the file a .sh script as well. Anyone knows its name? I've been searching for hours with no avail :/

Comment: You don't need a program to make runnable .jar files. You just need to have Main-Class: defined in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file inside the jar.
Why would the .sh script need more than java -jar Foo.jar ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: (1) ***[How to make an executable jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)*** (2) ***[making a jar file for console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497579/making-a-jar-file-for-console)*** (3) ***[How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/1164465)*** (4) ***[Build an executable jar file with Ant tool](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5959463/1164465)*** (5) ***[Eclipse: How to build an executable jar with external jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/502960/1164465)***

Answer (score 5):

The command line

```
java -jar file.jar
```

Will run your jar file if it has a `Main-Class` defined as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

You can use that command in a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can create  a runnable jar using NetBeans IDE or Eclipse IDE by just providing the main class to run. Rest of the things it will take automatically. That class must be having a `main()` method in it. Then you can run that jar file using `java -jar yourjarfile.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean actually coding java and then compiling to .jar? If you do try 
[eclipse code editor](http://www.eclipse.org/)

I used eclipse to make minecraft mods. It will work if you want to make .jar programs.

Comment: I'm using eclipse! The problem is that I'm using native libraries which Eclipse isn't putting into the jar correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a jar that you can execute using the usual syntax `./app.jar` (instead of `java -jar`), here is a post explaining the process: [how to create executable jars](https://dev.to/derlin/how-to-create-jars-that-run-like-any-other-executable-binary-appjar-ic3).

Basically, JAR is a variant of ZIP, which allows random bytes to be pre/appended to the JAR without corrrupting it. This means it is possible to prepend a launcher script at the beginning of the jar to make it "executable".

Here is a simple example of the process:

```sh
# Append a basic launcher script to the jar
cat \
  <(echo '#!/bin/sh')\
  <(echo 'exec java -jar $0 "$@"')\
  <(echo 'exit 0')\
  original.jar > executable.jar

# Make the new jar executable
chmod +x executable.jar
```

With this, you can now run `./executable.jar` instead of `java -jar original.jar`. This works on all **unix like systems** including Linux, MacOS, Cygwin, and Windows Linux subsystem.