# How to run jar file in AIX?

Tags: java, jar, aix

The question kinds of tell everything. I have a .jar file uploaded to an AIX server. I want to execute this jar. In the /usr I found the Java6, so I thought I could use it to run it, but I don't know how. Can someone tell me?

Comment: Is Java installed? What happens when you do `which java`?

Comment: I run it with `java` directly (inside the bin), so I try with that, but still doesn't execute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a runnable jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355623/how-to-make-a-runnable-jar-file)

Answer (score 3):

```
/usr/java6_64/jre/bin/java -jar /path/to/theapp.jar
```

Something like this should work