# jar file exception

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I'm trying to make runnable jar file of my java application. Each time I follow the steps of exporting application etc. It created a jar file for my application but when I run it, it shows popup 'java virtual machine. A java Exception has occurred'.
How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: How do you create the Jar file?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Just export to a runnable JAR by right clicking the project.

Comment: yes I'm using eclipse. Each I time I export my application to runnable jar file, it just makes an archive file instead of executable file.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, [JAR IS a ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))

> JAR files are fundamental archive files, built on the ZIP file format and have the .jar file extension

Just [run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)!

Comment: Then how will runnable jar be created? thanks for your response

Comment: sorry, wrong one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: Jar without manifest is just a zip, it's not runnable.

Comment: Dr.Y could please tell how to edit my manifest file for runnable jar

Comment: isn't there anyone to tell me?? stackoverfolwians??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355623/how-to-make-a-runnable-jar-file