# How to make a Runnable Jar file of my Project which contain Multiple JFrames which are interconnected with each other?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am new in Java and I am using Eclipse as an IDE. I mean to build a Windows Application using `JFrame` windows. My Project is Library Management System contains about 6 frames including 1 main frame which is Login Panel all others are open on the basis of the Login name and Password used.

What I want is to make a Run able Jar file which contains all frames.

How to make a runnable Jar file of my project which contains multiple frames which are interconnected with each other?

Comment: Create a jar that contains all the classes along with the main class and an entry in the jar's manifest. Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355623/how-to-make-a-runnable-jar-file

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is all contained in one project.

If it is go to `File` and click on `Export`. Click on the `Java` folder and select `Runnable JAR File`. Choose an export destination and then click on `Launch configuration`. If you did not set a custom launch configuration, it should be `<name of class you test it from> - Library Management System`. Hit `Finish` and hit `OK` on any of the errors (unless you don't want to continue with exporting).

Answer (score 1):

select project go to export as a runnable jar set main class and export it on some location.Go to that target folder double click over jar and run it.